# Why am I unable to access a Redux store in a child React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to understand how I can map my Redux state to a React component. I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here so I'll simply post the code and the error messages I receive.

**My redux store:**

```
const initialState = {
  userPosts: [{
    0: {
      content: 'Test post one',
      likes: 0
    },
    1: {
      content: 'Test post two',
      likes: 0
    },
    2: {
      content: 'Test post three',
      likes: 0
    }
  }]
}

console.log(initialState)

function likeReducer(state = initialState, action ){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LIKE':
      return {
        likes: state.likes  + 1
      };
      default:
        return state;
  }
}

function postReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'POST':
    return{
      userPosts: 'Test'
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({like: likeReducer, post: postReducer})
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Component} />
          <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react-app-root')
  );
};

render(App);
/*eslint-disable */
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    render(App)
  });
}
/*eslint-enable */
```

**The Component I'm trying to access the store in:**

```
import Post from './Post';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function LiveFeed(props){

  console.log(props)

  return(
    <div className="liveFeed">
    {props.userPosts.map((post, index) =>
       <Post content={post.content}
         likes={post.likes}
         />
     )}
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userPosts: state.userPosts
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LiveFeed);
```

**I am getting the follow console error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I've different variations of `this.props.userPosts`, `props.userPosts`, `userPosts` etc, to no avail.

Comment: Quite a few [related posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=redux+Uncaught+TypeError:+Cannot+read+property+%27map%27+of+undefined+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR0sKKqoriAhUEnq0KHW9oC9cQrQIoBDAAegQIBhAM&biw=1920&bih=928), in case they're helpful.

Comment: have you tried logging `state.userPosts` ? `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state); return {userPosts: state.userPosts}
};` I believe you have it set up correctly.

Comment: You can try adding a JSON.stringigy(this.props.userPosts) inside your render method.  If nothing shows up on the DOM than you know the information is not being sent from the reducer.

Comment: I've gotten this error before when my reducer sends over an Object and not an Array.  You cannot map over an object.

Answer (score 2):

It is connecting, it's just that your `userPosts` state should actually be under `state.post.userPosts`, rather than `state.userPosts` - in the `combineReducers` call you've specified that that posts state should go under the `post` subtree.

Try amending `state.userPosts` to `state.post.userPosts` in `mapStateToProps` and you should see it work.

Note, you'll also want to amend the structure of `initialState` accordingly - you should have a `like` object and a `post` object in there and then only pass the relevant subtree as the initial state in the appropriate reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  post: {
    userPosts: [{
      0: {
        content: 'Test post one',
        likes: 0
      },
      1: {
        content: 'Test post two',
        likes: 0
      },
      2: {
        content: 'Test post three',
        likes: 0
      }
    }]
  },
  like: {
    likes: 0
  }
}
```

Further note - it may be you actually want `state.userPosts` to exist, if that's the case then you should rework your reducers structure - do something like

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ userPosts: postReducer, ... })
```

And just have `postReducer` return an array of posts, rather than an object with a field `userPosts`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how that would look? My state is just an array of objects titled "userPosts" so don't I simply want to map that to the props?

Comment: That is your initialState object when you log it out, but then you subsequently do two things, 1) you supply the same initialState object to two different reducers, and 2) change the name of the reducers (and therefor the nested state objects) to "like" and "post" in your call to `combineReducers`. The first is pretty unorthodox and I wouldn't recommend doing that unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @JackCollins amended my answer to show you the structure of how your state will be according to your reducers setup - i.e. you want `state.post.userPosts`. Whether this is the structure you wanted is a different question - but that's what you have from the code above and it's why `state.userPosts` is undefined - it doesn't exist

Comment: @davincwil - I see, thank you for your help - you've put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Your reducers have different state objects and should have different initialStates.  In your `mapStateToProps` function, add a `console.log(state)` and you'll see what I mean. In that same function, you'll want to reference `state.post.userPosts`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply your store as the store to a `Provider` from `react-redux`. This can be done like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Route component={App} />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Comment: Thanks for your response - I do have the store supplied via the Provider.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend showing that code as well.